# Control the order and logic of how spring security runs the list of AuthenticationProviders

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Lets say I have multiple  **AuthenticationProviders** in my Spring application. such as :

```
   @Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws   Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(AAuthenticationProvider());
    auth.authenticationProvider(BAuthenticationProvider());
    auth.authenticationProvider(CAuthenticationProvider());     
}
```

by default spring security will try these providers in order until one provides a non-null response.

**Question**: Can I customize this behavior where I can can change the running order and logic of the list providers?

It seems that [ProviderManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.html) is somehow responsible of running this logic. would it be possible to override this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a convenient way to manipulate the order rather than just alter the order sequence in which you add your providers with `auth.authenticationProvider`.

The builder has an ArrayList that's appened at its end each time you call `auth.authenticationProvider`. And the evaluation is done in the same order as these providers are added to the list as well.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any direct solution from Spring. I was hoping to find something such as  the ability to create custom  **ProviderManager** . My workaround solution is to create one **Parent authenticationProvider** with one **parent UserDetailsService** where I can control flow of all UserDetailsServices .

You config class will include the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Autowired 
 UserDetailsService parentUserDetailsService;   

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.authenticationProvider(ParentAuthenticationProvider());    
  }

  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider ParentAuthenticationProvider() {
      DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
     authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(parentUserDetailsService);
    return authenticationProvider;
 }
}
```

The parent service  will have access to all child services. so it would look something like this:

```
@Service
public class ParentUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

 @Autowired
 UserDetailsService aUserDetailsService;

 @Autowired
 UserDetailsService bUserDetailsService;

 @Autowired
 UserDetailsService cUserDetailsService;

 @Override
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    UserDetails user = null;
    /* your logic will be here. 
       You iterate through all of the services 
       or have some conditional flow. the sky is your limit!
    */ 
    // For Example
    if(cond1)
       user = aUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    else(cond2){
       try{ 
          user = bUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
       }catch(Exception e){
         user = cUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
       }
    }

    return user;

}
```

I'm not sure if this is the most optimal solution, but it worked well in my case.